# What is the jessie/systemd equivalent to these two wheezy/sysvinit commands?

Tags: linux, debian, systemd

```
# Add a getty on the virtio console
echo 'V0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 115200 hvc0' | sudo tee -a wheezy/etc/inittab
# Automatically bring up eth0 using DHCP
printf '\nauto eth0\niface eth0 inet dhcp\n' | sudo tee -a wheezy/etc/network/interfaces
```

These come from a description (https://blog.nelhage.com/2013/12/lightweight-linux-kernel-development-with-kvm/) of getting a small debian virtual machine running. The base vm image is being touched up after generating with debootstrap, specifically the 'wheezy' path is the result of

```
debootstrap --include=openssh-server wheezy wheezy
```

Post-systemd, /etc/inittab and /etc/network/interfaces aren't used anymore. What commands would have equivalent functionality? Note that at this point in the setup we only have filesystem access - we don't have a running guest yet, so there is no running systemd to talk to.

Comment: 90% of systemd is service entries.

Comment: The `.config` given in the blog post will fail with systemd. You also have to set the right [kernel config options](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/README).